# How do you include .java files and .html files in a .jar file when you take Clean and Build in Netbeans 7?

Tags: jar, netbeans-7, createfile

If you have files in the build/classes/folderToJar Netbeans7 takes the .class files and make a .jar file when you take Clean and Build.

But how can you have .java files and .html files go into the .jarfile as well?

Answer (score 0):

First Create a package(Say html) under Source Packages

copy all of your html files to this package(when you create a package,a folder in the name of your package will be created inside your project src folder, so copy files to it)

You can access your html file from your program as

URL someURL = yourclass.class.getResource("/html/yourhtml.html");